# iOS how to get, current selected indexpath row on cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to make a link using label in every cell of table.

When the link is clicked, the table will get the **[indexpath row]** of the cell and we will use the index to match with the array index containing string data. The string will be sent to the next push page.

I'm using **UITapGestureRecognizer** to tap the label and put parameter to selector method.

How to get the current indexpath row the label on the selected cell?
This is my sample code :

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
...
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openUrl:) ];
gestureRec.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
gestureRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[cell.listPrice addGestureRecognizer:gestureRec];
[gestureRec release];
...
}


- (void)openUrl:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"DOwnload URL send >> %@",urlDownloadSend);
DownloadNowController *download =[[DownloadNowController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DownloadNowController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:download animated:YES];
[download release]; 
}
```

Comment: So what you want? you want when some one click on back button and coming back to your tableViewController should select the row which you selected before?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To determine the current selected cell you  can use next method of `UITableView`:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow
```

But I'm not sure that your cell will be selected after `UITapGestureRecognizer` fired.

I advice you to store row of the cell directly in `gestureRec.view` in `tag` property:

```
gestureRec.view.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Then in `openUrl` you can determine the selected cell by getting value of `sender.view.tag`

Comment: is there a tag property for gestureRec? I get an undefined method when i try to do this..

Comment: @bpn you are right, there is no `tag` property for `UIGestureRecognizer` but I have updated my answer to fit my idea.

Comment: thanks for updating, also it should be sender.view.tag to get the value of the tag..

Answer (score 3):

It is not very clear what you want to do.. do you have a link layed out on the `UITableViewCell` which triggers some other actions?

The [`UITableViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate) gives you some ***really cool*** methods called:

```
– tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:
– tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
– tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:
– tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:
```

When you tap a cell, the `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` are called - supplying you the currently selected [`NSIndexPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSIndexPath) which you can then use to get the row as follows:

```
indexPath.row;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a global variable to keep the value of `indexpath.row`

store the row in `didSelectRow:atIndexPath:` method

```
var = indexPath.row;
[tableView reloadData];

var = indexPath.row;
[tableView reloadData];
```

then use it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if(indexPath.row==var){
```

}

Comment: What is var hear??

Answer (score 1):

You may implement method `– tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in your `UITableViewDelegate`. There you can easily obtain information on indexPath.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

in cellForRowAtIndexPath data source method

```
UIImageView* selectedBg = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_selected.png"]];

cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBg;
[cell.backgroundView setNeedsDisplay];
[selectedBg release];
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code can be used to obtain the current selected indexpath row:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 NSLog(@"selected tableview row is %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
}
```